# Background transparency three.js shaderMaterial

Tags: three.js

I am having a spot of bother with a shader i am using for some tests with three.js.

When i apply it to a plane geometry it has a black background.

Ok, so i know that if i add "transparent: true" to my code that black background should go, which it does, however I am left with the actual star also being slightly transparent.

I have tried everything to try and make the star not transparent but the background transparent but to no avail.

The code im using for adding the shader to the plane geometry is.

```
uniforms = {
            resolution: { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(1.0,1.0) },
            baseStarTexture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/tex06.jpg') },
            overlayStarTexture : {type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/tex07.jpg') },
            time:         { type: "f", value: 0.5 }
        };

        uniforms.baseStarTexture.value.wrapS = uniforms.baseStarTexture.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        uniforms.overlayStarTexture.value.wrapS = uniforms.overlayStarTexture.value.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

        var itemMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            attributes: attributes,
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: vertShader,
            fragmentShader: fragShader,
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
            transparent: true,
            depthTest: true,
            depthWrite: false

        });

        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100), itemMaterial);
```

The fragment shader is as follows:

```
        uniform float noiseScale;
    uniform sampler2D overlayStarTexture;
    uniform sampler2D baseStarTexture;
    uniform float baseSpeed;
    uniform float alpha;
    uniform float time;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    uniform vec2 resolution;

    float snoise(vec3 uv, float res)    // by trisomie21
    {
        const vec3 s = vec3(1e0, 1e2, 1e4);

        uv *= res;

        vec3 uv0 = floor(mod(uv, res))*s;
        vec3 uv1 = floor(mod(uv+vec3(1.), res))*s;

        vec3 f = fract(uv); f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);

        vec4 v = vec4(uv0.x+uv0.y+uv0.z, uv1.x+uv0.y+uv0.z,
                      uv0.x+uv1.y+uv0.z, uv1.x+uv1.y+uv0.z);

        vec4 r = fract(sin(v*1e-3)*1e5);
        float r0 = mix(mix(r.x, r.y, f.x), mix(r.z, r.w, f.x), f.y);

        r = fract(sin((v + uv1.z - uv0.z)*1e-3)*1e5);
        float r1 = mix(mix(r.x, r.y, f.x), mix(r.z, r.w, f.x), f.y);

        return mix(r0, r1, f.z)*2.-1.;
    }

    float freqs[4];

    void main(void) {

        freqs[0] = texture2D( overlayStarTexture, vec2( 0.01, 0.25 ) ).x;
        freqs[1] = texture2D( overlayStarTexture, vec2( 0.07, 0.25 ) ).x;
        freqs[2] = texture2D( overlayStarTexture, vec2( 0.15, 0.25 ) ).x;
        freqs[3] = texture2D( overlayStarTexture, vec2( 0.30, 0.25 ) ).x;

        float brightness    = freqs[1] * 0.25 + freqs[2] * 0.25;
        float radius        = 0.24 + brightness * 0.2;
        float invRadius     = 1.0/radius;

        vec3 orange         = vec3( 0.8, 0.65, 0.3 );
        vec3 orangeRed      = vec3( 0.8, 0.35, 0.1 );
        float time          = time * 0.1;
        float aspect        = resolution.x/resolution.y; //This need to be viewport res x/y
        vec2 uv             = vUv/resolution.xy;
        vec2 p              = -0.5 + uv;
        p.x *= aspect;

        float fade      = pow( length( 2.0 * p ), 0.5 );
        float fVal1     = 1.0 - fade;
        float fVal2     = 1.0 - fade;

        float angle     = atan( p.x, p.y )/3.2832;
        float dist      = length(p);
        vec3 coord      = vec3( angle, dist, time * 0.1 );

        float newTime1  = abs( snoise( coord + vec3( 0.0, -time * ( 0.35 + brightness * 0.001 ), time * 0.015 ), 15.0 ) );
        float newTime2  = abs( snoise( coord + vec3( 0.0, -time * ( 0.15 + brightness * 0.001 ), time * 0.015 ), 45.0 ) );
        for( int i=1; i<=5; i++ ){
            float power = pow( 2.8, float(i + 1) );
            fVal1 += ( 0.5 / power ) * snoise( coord + vec3( 0.0, -time, time * 0.2 ), ( power * ( 10.0 ) * ( newTime1 + 1.0 ) ) );
            fVal2 += ( 0.5 / power ) * snoise( coord + vec3( 0.0, -time, time * 0.2 ), ( power * ( 25.0 ) * ( newTime2 + 1.0 ) ) );
        }

        float corona        = pow( fVal1 * max( 1.1 - fade, 0.0 ), 2.0 ) * 50.0;
        corona              += pow( fVal2 * max( 1.1 - fade, 0.0 ), 2.0 ) * 25.0;
        corona              *= 1.5 - newTime1;
        vec3 starSphere     = vec3( 0.0 );

        vec2 sp = -1.0 + 2.0 * uv;
        sp.x *= aspect;
        sp *= ( 2.0 - brightness );
        float r = dot(sp,sp);
        float f = (1.0-sqrt(abs(1.0-r)))/(r) + brightness * 0.5;
        if( dist < radius ){
            corona          *= pow( dist * invRadius, 24.0);
            vec2 newUv;
            newUv.x = sp.x*f;
            newUv.y = sp.y*f;
            newUv += vec2( time, 0.0 );

            vec3 texSample  = texture2D( baseStarTexture, newUv ).rgb;
            float uOff      = ( texSample.g * brightness * 4.5 + time * 25.0 ); //This alters the speed of the star surface
            vec2 starUV     = newUv + vec2( uOff, 0.0);
            starSphere      = texture2D( baseStarTexture, starUV ).rgb;
        }

        float starGlow  = min( max( 7.8 - dist * ( 25.0 - brightness ), 0.0 ), 0.5 );
        gl_FragColor.rgb    = vec3( f * ( 0.75 + brightness * 0.3 ) * orange ) + starSphere + corona * orange + starGlow * orangeRed;
        gl_FragColor.a      = 1.0;
    }
```

And the vertex shader is :

```
    varying vec2 vUv;
varying vec3 vNormal;
attribute float displacement;
void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    vNormal = normal;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                  modelViewMatrix *
                  vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Also if i change the blending from "THREE.AdditiveBlending" it just makes the plane show again which is why its set on that.

But please let me know if i'm being a fool!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Russell.